# Select and Update in same time and gets displayed

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT MIN(id),CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,runNo,ResponseLength  
  FROM  `RequestInfo`
  WHERE  `CustomerName` =  'Hotstar'
    AND `ResponseContentType` like '%video/MP2T%'
    AND `RequestHttpRequest` like '%segment%' ;
```

which gives me output like this:-

```
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------------+----------+
| MIN(id) | CustomerName | Scenario | StepNo | InTransit | IsAlef | runNo | ResponseLength | IsActive |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------------+----------+
|     139 | HotStar      | SearchTv | 1      | No        | No     | 1     | 410098         |     NULL |
+---------+--------------+----------+--------+-----------+--------+-------+----------------+----------+
```

I want to insert string "Yes" in the last column i.e "IsActive" when the above data is being displayed but only when the IsActive is set as NULL.

Comment: UPDATE TABLE SET isActive = 'Yes' WHERE  `CustomerName` =  'Hotstar' AND `ResponseContentType` like '%video/MP2T%' AND `RequestHttpRequest` like '%segment%' AND isActive is NULL

Comment: do you want to only return the value "Yes" in the select statement, or do you want to save it too?

Comment: Please ask the shortest possible questions. Remove all the stuff which is not necessary. Ask the generic question, which is relevant in general. This is a courtesy to your readers.

Comment: @DrIvol  i want to save it too

Comment: @Zelldon i want to set "Yes" only for that row which has minimum id no.

Comment: is Active is the filed of RequestInfo table?

Comment: @Assen yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below query

```
Update RequestInfo R inner join (SELECT MIN(id) as id,CustomerName, Scenario,StepNo,InTransit,IsAlef,runNo,ResponseLength  
  FROM  `RequestInfo`
  WHERE  `CustomerName` =  'Hotstar'
    AND `ResponseContentType` like '%video/MP2T%'
    AND `RequestHttpRequest` like '%segment%')as T on R.id = T.id set R.isAcitve ='Yes' Where  R.id = T.id;
```

Comment: Thanks it worked also there is a typo mistake. Also  can we display the results along with the update.